2013 27" iMac won't boot on Any MacOS but perfectly on WIndows
recently i bought this iMac to a guy who has been using it on windows since many years ago.
Now i want to use MacOS as it is normal, but i can't manage to make it even boot into the installer.
First. i tried making a bootable usb with terminal in other mac but it'll get stopped on the apple logo screen. then, i tried with the recovery and internet recovery; neither of those ended up in the installer, all frozen charging screens. Then, more desperately, i tried using directly OCLP with monterrey, and surprisingly managed to get into the installer and install, but on the last reboot before it will start, it stopped in different lines like "exiting with abnormal code 1 ".
idk what more to do. Its kinda strange cause using windows it works more than well.
by the way, it has the i7 4771 and the 775M 2Gb. 16 Gb of Ram.
Thankss.
